# How to put in foreground an Android activity that is in background

Tags: android, android-activity

I read several similar questions here, but I didn't find a clear reply to my question.

- I launch my Android App and I have my main `ActivityA` in foreground
- after some time I push a `button` (of `ActivityA`) and I open (and put in foreground, then visible and ontop) `ActivityB`. I do it simply by the command `myContext.startActivity(myIntent);`
- It means  that now `ActivityA` is in background (`onPause()`), then not visible.
- After some time I push another `button` of `ActivityB` with the target to put in foreground (then visible and `ontop`) again previous `ActivityA`
- What is the correct and best way to do it? According to my understanding (but I'm not sure it's correct.) it shouldn't be by `startActivity()`, because `startActivity()` creates another instance of `ActivityA` (it calls `onCreate()` ) and then there will be 2 instances of `ActivityA` running (one in foreground and one in background).  What I want to get is a calling of `onResume()` for `ActivityA` (and not of `onCreate()` ).
- The second question is: how can I know if `ActivityA` is still alive in background? Maybe after sometime the system killed it to free resources.

Note: the solution in my case cannot be to use `finish()` to destroy `ActivityA` when I open `ActivityB`, and then to use `startActivity()` to reopen it, because I need `ActivityA` alive as much as possible.

Thank you very much in Advance
Fausto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) when starting a new activity. This will cause a background activity to be be brought to the foreground if it's running, or create a new instance if it's not running at all.

From inside ActivityB:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: ; thank you very much; I'll try... But How can I verify if AvtivityA is still running or not?

Comment: The android system takes care of that. If you manually want to check whether it is in the backstack, investigate it using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html

Comment: it looks good... according to another answer I don't understand if it is better to use  FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. Can you clarify please?

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is a bit more destructive in a sense that it finishes activites beyond the one that launches the intent and the target activity. I would prefer FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT in your case, but as always, it depends on your needs. Here's more information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Answer (score 1):

> What is the correct and best way to do it?

Use `startActivity()`, with an `Intent` on which you have added `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`.

> it shouldn't be by startActivity(), because startActivity() creates another instance of ActivityA

While that is the default behavior, `Intent` flags can alter that behavior.

> how can I know if ActivityA is still alive in background?

If you did not `finish()` it, and your process has not been terminated, it exists.

> Maybe after sometime the system killed it to free resources.

Android terminates processes to free up system RAM. It does not destroy activities on its own.

> because I need Activity A alive as much as possible

To be honest, that suggests that you have other architectural issues. Bear in mind that activities are destroyed and recreated for various reasons, such as configuration changes (e.g., screen rotation). Activities should be very disposable.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I'm going to try the code. Just last small question: what happen if  I use "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT", but the ActivityB was never created before? can it create problems?  ps: I would like to accept your answer, but I don't have reputation yet :-(    hoping somebody will increase my reputation to do that...

Comment: @Fausto70: I assume that you really mean ActivityA. If there is no ActivityA instance, a fresh one will be created.

Answer (score 1):

```
    You can use following
    1. For launching new instance (current state of ActivityA) and get ActivityA on Top of Stack

       Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
       startActivity(intent);

    2. For launching old instance and get ActivityA on Top of Stack

       Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
       startActivity(intent);

   For more detail please check
```

[Task and Back Task](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Comment: Thank you... but reading Android documentation it seems the opposite (maybe due to my bad english...):  FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP: "If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.".  It seems that I have only to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, so if Activity B is already running, it is not created, if it is not running, it will be created.  Am I right?

Comment: Thanks @Fausto70 , I have modified the answer. Please take a look

Answer (score -1):

You can use StartActivityForResult in the place of StartActivity in activity A and on activity B you can setResult when you want to open Activity A again.In that case OnActivityResult() of activity A is called not onCreate().